# Error when passing deviceToken from AppDelegate to another class in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I create this variable in AppDelegate to store deviceToken and then passing it to another class

```
var deviceTokenToPass:NSData?

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {


     deviceTokenToPass = deviceToken


}
```

In another class I'm trying to pass deviceToken to Parse.com but I have exception in the line of passing value of deviceToken

```
let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

let deviceToken = delegate.deviceTokenToPass




var currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()

currentInstallation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)  // Exception in this line
currentInstallation.channels = ["global"]

currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
```

The same line it's working true when I'm putting it inside AppDelegate but I want to store this data at another class

Comment: What kind of error you are getting?

Comment: What's the exception reason?

Comment: You must make sure that when you call this function, the deviceToken is received (`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` called).

Comment: @JigarTarsariya It was giving null but now It's working true I didn't change anything ! :D

Comment: Why are you saving the device token in the other class?  The token arrives asynchronously so the deviceToken may not be set when you are trying to access it. It is simpler to just update the PFInstallation from the app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You need unwrap it

```
if let deviceToken = delegate.deviceTokenToPass
{
    var currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()

    currentInstallation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    currentInstallation.channels = ["global"]

    currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
}
```